# incompatible types boolean cannot be converted to Usuarios

Tags: java, web-service, netbeans

Estou criando uma função para inserir novos usuarios no banco, porem apresente essa erro: "incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to Usuarios". Alguém sabe uma forma de solucionar esse caso:

```
public String InsertUserCpf(@PathParam("nome")String nome,
        @QueryParam("email") String email,
        @QueryParam("senha") String senha,
        @QueryParam("dtnasc") Date dtnasc,
        @QueryParam("fone") String fone,
        @QueryParam("oab") String oab,
        @QueryParam("cep") String cep,
        @QueryParam("cpf") String cpf)
{
    Usuarios u = new Usuarios();
    u.setNome(nome);
    u.setEmail(email);
    u.setSenha(senha);
    u.setDtnasc(dtnasc);
    u.setFone(fone);
    u.setOab(oab);
    u.setCep(cep);
    u.setCpf(cpf);

    UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();
    u = dao.inserir(u);

    Gson g = new Gson();
    return g.toJson(u);
}
```

UsuarioDao.java:

```
public boolean inserir(Usuarios usuario)
    {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome,email,senha,dtnasc,fone,oab,cep,cpf) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        Boolean retorno = false;
        PreparedStatement pst = Conexao.getPreparedStatement(sql);
        try {
            pst.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
            pst.setString(2, usuario.getEmail());
            pst.setString(3, usuario.getSenha());
            pst.setDate(4, usuario.getDtnasc());
            pst.setString(5, usuario.getFone());
            pst.setString(6, usuario.getOab());
            pst.setString(7, usuario.getCep());
            pst.setString(8, usuario.getCpf());

            if(pst.executeUpdate()>0)
            {
                retorno = true;
            }



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            retorno = false;
        }

        return retorno;

    }
```

Comment: Onde ocorre o erro? Qual linha?

Comment: nesse comando que aparece o erro:   u = dao.inserir(u);

Comment: Retornar `boolean` para sinalizar se deu erro ou não é uma péssima prática de programação. Isso esconde os erros, as suas causas e dificulta a sua recuperação. Foi exatamente para que os programadores não fizessem isso, que as exceções foram inventadas, portanto, use-as.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note que você declara um `Usuario u` e depois o faz **receber** o método `inserir()` que retorna um **boolean** e não um usuário. Ou seja, são tipos diferentes. Observe:

```
Usuarios u = new Usuarios(); // aqui você instancia
u.setNome(nome);
u.setEmail(email);
u.setSenha(senha);
u.setDtnasc(dtnasc);
u.setFone(fone);
u.setOab(oab);
u.setCep(cep);
u.setCpf(cpf);

UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();
u = dao.inserir(u); // aqui tenta receber em "u" o retorno de dao.inserir() 
                    //que no caso é um boolean (true ou false) e não um Usuario
Gson g = new Gson();
return g.toJson(u);
```

Pelo que entendi, o método inserir retorna um `boolean` que refere-se ao sucesso da inserção. Logo sua lógica ficaria algo assim:

```
boolean sucesso = false;
sucesso = dao.inserir(u);

if (sucesso) { // sucesso ao inserir
    Gson g = new Gson();
    return g.toJson(u);
    //...
}
```

Porém, como o @Victor Stafusa mencionou, utilizar `boolean` para retornar erros é uma má prática de programação, ao invés disso utilize [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html)

Comment: Lembrando que retornar `boolean` para indicar sucesso ou erro é uma má prática de programação.

Comment: Obrigada @Zulian, resolveu o problema e vou tentar agora incluir Exceptions. Obrigada pela dica